# Missing Package Dependency - CentOS - Amazon EC2

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2, yum, dependencies

After running `yum update --skip-broken` I get the following:

```
Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    aws-cli-1.1.0-1.3.amzn1.noarch from amzn-main
    1:perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib-2.020-129.el6.x86_64 from centos
    python-bcdoc-0.10.0-1.0.amzn1.noarch from amzn-main
    python-botocore-0.17.0-1.2.amzn1.noarch from amzn-main
    python-rsa-3.1.2-4.3.amzn1.noarch from amzn-main
```

What can I do to resolve these dependency problems?

Any help is appreciated!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Amazon's Linux?  If yes:

Appears perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib-2.020-129.el6.x86_64 was installed from CentOS and it is not compatible with Amzn.

You way want to try removing  perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib-2.020-129.el6.x86_64 then install the one that Amazon provides:

```
yum erase perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib
yum install perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib
```

Before you do this, check to assure that a CentOS repo is not installed in /etc/yum.repos.d.

Once you have installed the AMZN version of the perl module, you can then try to re-install the aws-cli.